# Android: SoundPool / record Audio

Tags: java, android, audio, sdk, soundpool

I want to record different sound and play it with the "SoundPool" on my Phone.
At the moment I save the sounds in the "\res\raw" folder und load it with a hashMap.

I hope you can help me.

```
this.setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
spool = new SoundPool(1, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);
soundsMap = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
soundsMap.put(1, spool.load(context, R.raw.alan1, 1));
soundID = soundsMap.get(1);
AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);
float volume = (float) audioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);

loopPool = spool.play(soundID, volume, volume, 5, 0, 1f);
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't say what problem you're running in to, but your volume handling is incorrect.
The volume specified in `SoundPool.play()` is supposed to be a floating point value from 0.0 to 1.0, while the return value of `AudioManager.getStreamVolume()` is an integer between 0 and `AudioManager.getStreamMaxVolume()`.

You should just specify a volume of 1.0 (or less), and the system will scale it accordingly.